# Is there a proof that $L^p([0,1],X)$ has the Radon Nikodym Property that uses the characterization via Lipschitz continuous functions?

Tags: bochner-spaces, lipschitz-functions

I'm looking for an alternative proof of the following theorem: Let $1<p<\infty$ then $L^p([0,1],X)$ has the Radon Nikodym property iff $X$ does. The theorem is due to [Sundaresan](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123677900581) and an alternative proof was given by [Turett & Uhl](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1976-061-02/S0002-9939-1976-0423069-3/)

I was wondering if there exists a proof of this Theorem, using this characterization: $X$ has the Radon Nikodym property iff every Lipschitz continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ is differentiable a.e.

Does anyone know a source for this?

Comment: Please look at Theorem 1.1 here: http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v157-n1-p05.pdf

Comment: I looked at the theorem but I don't really see the connection to my question. In order to prove the RNP of $L^p([0,1],X)$ I would have to show that any Lipschitz continuous function on an interval with values in $L^p([0,1],X)$  is differentiable a.e. But Theorem 1.1 makes notes about functions whose codomain is already known to have the RNP. Did I miss something here?